# java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on okhttp3.Address@46888237

Tags: java, ioexception, okhttp

This is the code:

```
//OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
    .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "username=tokenaccess&password=test123");
```

Produce the error:

> java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on okhttp3.Address@46888237

Comment: i am also having same error can anyone please tell me how to resolve it ? I am using dynamic tab in which 10 tab is there now ,when i am calling API,sometimes its coming properly for 2 to 3 tab after that i am getting these error i searched every where but i am not getting proper answer which will solve my issue.if anyone knows how to fix it please tell me...

Answer (score 0):

Network status is bad when the question appears, the request returns , but the response is null.

I deal it with "outoftime exception", so far did not affect the program.